# How to open google maps using plain html

Tags: html, google-maps

All I want is simple yet I am unable to find a solution. Basically, I have a list of images displayed using `ul li` tag.  When the user clicks one of the items, I want the browser to open a new tab or window and pass a certain postcode to be displayed on Google Maps site. How can I achieve this. I have read about Google Map API but I think this is too much for what I want.

here is a sample of my code:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href=""><img src="image1.jpg" id="SE325JP"></a></li>
   <li><a href=""><img src="image1.jpg" id="NP125JL"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can just send a query string of `Latitude` and `Longitude` to Google Map in your `href` like this:

```
 <!-- https://maps.google.com/?q=<lat>,<lng> -->
 <a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=46.860191,3.779297">
      <img src="PATH TO YOUR IMAGE"/>
 </a>
```

Or send the `address`:

```
<!-- https://maps.google.com/?q=<address> -->
<a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=58250 Montaron, France">
       <img src="PATH TO YOUR IMAGE"/>
</a>
```

There are many parameters which you can set while you are sending your query. For instance, if you add `&t=m` at the end of `href` link the normal map will be displayed instead of satellite map. Like this:

```
<!-- https://maps.google.com/?q=<address> -->
<a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=58250 Montaron, France&t=m">
       <img src="PATH TO YOUR IMAGE"/>
</a>
```

For a complete list of parameters see [Everything You Never Wanted to Know About Google Maps' Parameters](http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters) or [Google Maps Query String Parameters](http://asnsblues.blogspot.se/2011/11/google-maps-query-string-parameters.html).

See [`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sam_rad/vSRJ2) Demo